# Worker thread created inside service

Tags: android, multithreading, service

To run long operation in service we have to create a separate worker thread inside service , so that the main thread is not blocked (for preventing ANR exception )

My **doubt** is , the service is supposed to run on main thread , so **if** the **main thread is idle** , how can the **service be still running** ( and the **worker thread also** created by the service ) .

Comment: check [IntentService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java) sources for example to see how its implemented

Comment: and? what is not clear?

Comment: My doubt is, how is the thread getting the context when the main thread is free ? Where is the service if not on main thread ?

Comment: `"how is the thread getting the context"`? the `Service` is a `Context` - no need for any method that gets the `Context`

Comment: Sorry , but I am not getting it . See a service is always supposed to run on main thread . So , when main thread is empty(but service is alive) then where is this service running or getting stored ? Like when the activity is not visible it gets store in the task stack .